# Using ReactJS to render components within Aurelia

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aurelia

## Goal

To create, what is in my opinion, an almost perfect framework I want to use [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io) in combination with [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) (mainly just creating components which can be used within Aurelia).

To achieve this there are several options (See http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/03/how-to-use-react-js-in-aurelia/ and https://github.com/bryanrsmith/aurelia-react-loader)

The first option has the downside that the component is wrapped within a custom element, which I don't want to do for all elements I plan on creating. The second option is pretty nice, wasn't it that the component is generated from a component instance (instead of the html markup).

## Work already done

The thing I've been trying to do now is to create a custom attribute which makes ReactJS render the innerHTML of the specific element.

```
import { customAttribute, inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

// ToDo: have one file to import all dependent components
import { MyReactComponent } from 'components/my-react-component';

@inject(Element)
@customAttribute('react-content')
export default class ReactCustomAttribute {
    constructor (element) {
        console.log(element.innerHTML);
        this.element = element;
        ReactDOM.render(
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.element.innerHTML}}></div>, 
            this.element);
        // ReactDOM.render(
        //     <MyReactComponent><h2>lol</h2><h2>lol</h2></MyReactComponent>, 
        //     this.element);
    }
}
```

If the solution above would work I'd be absolutely happy. But, as Aurelia wants to comply to web standards it puts all element names to lowercase. (`this.element.innerHTML` returns `<myreactcomponent><h2>lol</h2><h2>lol</h2></myreactcomponent>`) This way ReactJS can't render the components.

The piece I've commented out in the code snippet above actually works.

## Questions

- How can I get ReactJS to properly render these components?

  - Is it possible to configure Aurelia to not turn element names to lowercase?
  - Is it possible for ReactJS to see the relationship between html elements written in kebab-case and javascript class names?

Comment: Hi, did u done ur task? and am working aurelia - react, view react model is aurelia, here i have a click function in my view(react) **onClick={this.myfun}** while clicking it needs to take it to aurelia where the myfun is. any idea.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get ReactJS to properly render these components?

You have to do that in attached() method of your aurelia view model.

> Is it possible to configure Aurelia to not turn element names to lowercase?

The correct answer is **"there is no case"**
Tag and attribute names are case insensitive in HTML.
And Aurelia is standards based.

> Is it possible for ReactJS to see the relationship between html elements written in kebab-case and javascript class names?

This one will need some teaching.
You can look at how Aurelia treats naming conventions in the source
https://github.com/aurelia/templating/blob/master/src/html-behavior.js

Answer (score 0):

Attached method of aurelia will not wait until complete DOM is ready, if we are doing any DOM manipulations inside attached will fail..